# How do I calculate the length of a transmission line?

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, homework, radiation

[image]

A quick translation:

Generator has \$Z_g = 50\Omega\$ and 12 V. The line is loaded with an unknown RL. We observe we have a maximum of 8 V at 250 MHz and a minimum at 500 MHz.

1. Solution: Asks for the dielectrical permitivity and the \$Z_o\$ of the line

   $$Z_o = \sqrt{L/C} = 50\Omega$$

   and for the dielectrical permitivity of the dielectric it is

   $$Z_o = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_o \epsilon_r}{\mu_o \mu_r}}$$

   $$Z_o = 120\pi \cdot \sqrt{1/3}$$

   from there we get the dielectrical permitivity.
2. This asks for the line length which is **my initial question**. Is wavelength same as the line length or am I wrong?

$$\lambda = \frac{v}{f} = 0.159 m$$

Thanks and sorry for my lack of English in Electrical Engineering subject.

Comment: Perhaps you meant *length*?

Comment: yeah, i did mean that.

Comment: If 500MHz is 3/4λ  and  250MHz is 1/2λ  what is length?

Comment: My question: Calculating Lambda that way i did, the result is also the electrical length of the transmission line?. I mean, the line has a length of 0.159 meters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signal Velocity = \$v_s=\dfrac {c}{\sqrt{\epsilon _r}}\$

\$\lambda=\dfrac{v_s}{f}\$

Comment: Yeah, lambda is the wave length but... what about the transmission line?

Comment: Max amplitude for unknown load could be 1/2, 1, 3/2 λ  , and Min amplitude could be 1/4, 3/4, 5/4, λ

Comment: Funny how people overthink microwave equations lol.

Comment: It's from Radiation and Wave Guidance. The exams are quite difficult (for me)